# Angular hybrid application with UpgradeModule controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, hybrid

I aim to upgrade a large AngularJS app with UpgradeModule so I can run AngularJS and Angular 6 side-by-side without doing the preparation phase, which tells you to follow AngularJS style-guide.

I wonder if it is possible when you have a lot of controllers similar to this one:

```
 angular.module("MyModule").controller($scope, function ($scope) {
    // code here.
 };
```

My question is: Does UpgradeModule works only if you have AngularJS components? So far it's not successful with my already written controllers. I can see a working example here and they are only using AngularJS components:

[UpgradeModule without preparation](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngUpgrade-without-preparation/blob/master/src/ng1/phone-detail/phone-detail.component.js)

Can someone please advice me if I need to convert my AngularJS controllers to components?

Answer (score 2):

After reading the documentation, **I guess you need to have component directives to work with ng-upgrade.** 
In the preparation phase of migration, it has mentioned using component directives so that it works with angular.

According to documentation:

To be Angular compatible, an AngularJS component directive should configure these attributes:

restrict: 'E'. Components are usually used as elements.

scope: {} - an isolate scope. In Angular, components are always isolated from their surroundings, and you should do this in AngularJS too.

bindToController: {}. Component inputs and outputs should be bound to the controller instead of using the $scope.

controller and controllerAs. Components have their own controllers.
template or templateUrl. Components have their own templates.